# Java 8 cryptography issue

Tags: java-8, ssl-certificate, sslhandshakeexception

I have developed a biometric authencation system on `java8u144` and active directory password reset using `ldaps` on `java8u191`. When I tried to combine them...
Forst biometric encryption popped error for invalid key size. I updated `JCE UNLIMITED` .THEN BIOMETRIC STARTED WORKING BUT `ldaps` connection issues remain for `ssl` handshake `pkix` path building failed

I am not able to fix it

Pls help me out
I am running out of time

i am getting following exception

```
%% Invalidated:  [Session-1, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384]
http-nio-8084-exec-2, SEND TLSv1.2 ALERT:  fatal, description = certificate_unknown
http-nio-8084-exec-2, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Alert, length = 2
[Raw write]: length = 7
0000: 15 03 03 00 02 02 2E                               .......
http-nio-8084-exec-2, called closeSocket()
http-nio-8084-exec-2, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

on java8u144 without jce code was working but biometric needed unlimited strength. i tried java8u144 java8u162 java8u191
currently using java8u162.
```

above exception is coming only after JCE upgrade.

kindly guide how to get certificate chain for this.

NOTE `LDP.exe` is working on client sucessfully.
& `OPENSSL`  : unable to verify first cerificate

Comment: Post the code part where you are getting issue along with exception you are getting. How you are doing ssl handshake ?

Comment: any particular reason not to use same java versions on both side ? Have you tried making java versions consistent ?

Comment: @AshwinK i have edited my post pls check